# Creating a vagrant box using `vagrant package` on windows

Tags: windows, vagrant

So, I'm trying to run `vagrant package` on my current Vagrant VM, and it seems to be working fine(no errors reported); however, it is not saving the file to the location that it reports to be saving it. I cannot locate the file anywhere else on the system either, so I'm not sure if it's actually being created or if the command is silently failing.

I am running Vagrant 1.6.1 on Windows 8.1 and using virtualbox as my hypervisor. Are there logs that I can be looking at which might help diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. This is specifically related to using vagrant on windows with mingw. A DLL dependency is screwed up for bsdtar, so if you follow the steps in http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2150/, you should be fine.